# Programa que valide números y los guarde. En C

Tags: c

Estoy tomando un curso introductorio a C, me atoré un poco en lo siguiente:
Quiero realizar un algoritmo que pida al usuario una entrada, si esta es mayor que 10 el algortimo arroja mensaje de numero correcto y lo guarda, de lo contrario manda mensaje de error y continua pidiendo un numero:

He hecho esto pero no cumple lo que yo esperaria:: creo que el error es cuando marco que >=10

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    float n;
        if (scanf("%f", &n)>=10) {
            printf("%f fue leido correctamente!\n", n);
            }
        else printf("no pude leer la variable num.\n");
        
}
```

en general, si pongo un numero mayor que  10 hace todo lo contrario que espero que haga

Comment: `scanf` retorna el número de elementos leidos. O sea, retorna siempre el valor 1. Hay que leer la documentación ...

Answer (score -2):

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    float n;
//Primero debes tener el valor a evaluar en una variable dado que es necesario para verificar si se cumple la condicion o no
    scanf("%f", &n);
// si lo haces de la manera anterior no funciona, debido a que la funcion scanf() no retorna nada al leer el valor y es interpretado como una respuesta no valida o falsa
        if ( n >=10 ) {
            printf("%f fue leido correctamente!\n", n);
            }
        else printf("no pude leer la variable num.\n");
        
}
```

prueba de esta manera a ver que tal.

Comment: Una respuesta debe identificar el problema, explicar la solución. El puro código no será muy útil ni educativo.

Comment: ya le hice una edicion un poco mas explicativa, de lo que considero era el problema, gracias por la aclaracion